# $F$ is purely inseparable over $K$ if and only if the only $K$-monomorphism $F \to C$ is the inclusion map.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $C$ be an algebraically closed field, and $F,K$ are fields with $K\subseteq F\subseteq C$. How to show that $F$ is purely inseparable over $K$ if and only if the only $K$-monomorphism $F \to C$ is the inclusion map?

Comment: I am learning Galois theory. I remember there is a proposition saying that $E/F$ is totally inseparable $\iff \{E : F\} = 1$ where $\{E : F\}$ is number of $F$-monomorphism $\sigma : E \hookrightarrow \overline{F}$. Maybe this would help.

Comment: Besides, I don't see how $E$ is used in the question. Is there a typo? Should it be $K \subseteq F \subseteq C$ instead of $K \subseteq E, F \subseteq C$? Also, are you implicitly assuming all extensions are algebraic?

Answer (score 1):

Couple of hints.

In one direction, if $\Phi\colon F\to C$ is a homomorphism of $K$-algebras, then for any element $\alpha\in F$ you have $p_\alpha(\Phi(\alpha))=0$, where $p_\alpha$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $F$.

In the other direction, if $p$ is an irreducible polynomial over $K$ with distinct roots $\alpha_1,\alpha_2\in C$, then $K[\alpha_1]\cong K[\alpha_2]$ and the isomorphism extends to an automorphism of $C$.

Answer (score 0):

This statement is not true .
Consider F be a finite extension of degree $n(>0)$ over  $K=\mathbb{Q}$,  which is the field of rational numbers. Then any $\mathbb{Q}$ algebra from $K$ to the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ is always injective. But F is never be a inseperableble
extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. Hence the statement is false

If you consider the map $F\hookrightarrow C$ is just a vector space homomorphism, then above example shows that the converse is not true.

Comment: I don't really get your point. So what if it's injective? Field homomorphisms are always injective, but how does that relate to the problem?

Comment: The above example is a counterexample which shows that the statement

Comment: How is it a counterexample?

Answer (score 0):

Repeating again
 $K=\mathbb{Q}\subset F=\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{3}]\subset C=\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$ is a seperable extension and any nonzero K algebra homomorphism  $F\hookrightarrow C$ is injective.